# What is stringConverter as (String) -> String?

Tags: swift

Can anyone explain what `stringConverter as (String) -> String` in combination with `things.append({ (name: String) -> String in "Hello, \(name)" })` actually do?

(Source: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TypeCasting.html)

I think an anonymous function is added to the `collection` and later gives it a name in the switch statement to work with it...

Comment: It just casts `stringConverter` to a "function" type that accepts a string type and returns a string type

Comment: Can you also add the relevant code, so people won't have to grok through the whole documentation page? It will also prevent this question to become invalid if the contents of that page change/disappear.

Answer (score 2):

`things` is an `Array` that has no constraint on what it can contain...

```
var things: [Any] = []
```

And it contains all sorts of different types...

```
things.append(0) // Int
things.append(0.0) // Double
things.append(42)
things.append(3.14159)
things.append("hello") // String
things.append((3.0, 5.0)) // (Double, Double) tuple
things.append(Movie(name: "Ghostbusters", director: "Ivan Reitman")) // Movie struct
things.append({ (name: String) -> String in "Hello, \(name)" })
```

The last line above adds a function that takes a `String` and returns a `String`. `(String) -> String`.

When iterating over this array we have to determine what each object is as they could be anything.

The pattern matching of `switch` and `case` allows us to do this...

```
for thing in things {
    switch thing {
    case 0 as Int:
        print("zero as an Int")
    case 0 as Double:
        print("zero as a Double")
    case let someInt as Int:
        print("an integer value of \(someInt)")
    case let someDouble as Double where someDouble > 0:
        print("a positive double value of \(someDouble)")
    case is Double:
        print("some other double value that I don't want to print")
    case let someString as String:
        print("a string value of \"\(someString)\"")
    case let (x, y) as (Double, Double):
        print("an (x, y) point at \(x), \(y)")
    case let movie as Movie:
        print("a movie called \(movie.name), dir. \(movie.director)")
    case let stringConverter as (String) -> String:
        print(stringConverter("Michael"))
    default:
        print("something else")
    }
}
```

What this bit does...

```
    case let stringConverter as (String) -> String:
        print(stringConverter("Michael"))
```

Is saying... "create a new variable from the `thing` called `stringConverter` and cast it to a `(String) -> String` type. If that works then we pattern match on it and print the result of the function".

It's not actually changing the type of the `thing` it's just using the ability to cast it as a pattern matching mechanism to satisfy the `switch/case`.